# Number of votes needed to close a question

Tags: discussion, moderators, closing

I know it takes 5 votes all of which are from non-moderators to close a question. However, I have noticed that it only takes one vote from a moderator to close a question. I don't understand why a moderator has such power to close a question, is there some explanation for this?

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of power would you want the moderators to have?

Comment: [List of all diamond moderator powers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/151385)

Answer (score 11):

Basically for cleanup. There are various types of questions (e.g. spam, questions that are clearly not about mathematics) that just don't belong here, but waiting for five people to close them is just wasting the time of four people. Some of these questions most people never see because the moderators also delete them, which is exactly the idea; they shouldn't be cluttering up the site.

When a moderator votes to close as off-topic they also have the option of migrating the question to any other SE site. As I understand it, non-moderators can *suggest* such a migration, but it is quicker and easier just to have a moderator do it.

Comment: Emphasis on "**any other SE site**". Right now non-moderators can only vote to migrate questions to Physics, Stats, or Meta. By flags or comments user can suggest other migration targets; but only moderators can migrate questions to say, Academia, Computational Science, Mathematica, or TeX.